# Why jmeter doesn't reach the expected rate?

Tags: jmeter

I've configured my jmeter as can be seen in the screen shot below-
[image]

However, when I examine the logs I can see that we only got to a rate of 37 requests per second as can be seen in the logs:
*2021-10-18 03:20:30,005 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary = 3510096 in 26:26:03 =   36.9/s Avg:    67 Min:    16 Max: 69589 Err:    61 (0.00%)*

Am I missing something? How can I increase the rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What rate is "expected"?

1 user will generate 1 hit per second only if application response time will be 1000 milliseconds.

If response time will be 2000 milliseconds you will have 0.5 requests per second

If response time will be 500 milliseconds you will have 2 requests per second.

There could be 2 explanations for the throughput lower than expected:

1. JMeter cannot send requests fast enough the reasons are in:

   - The number of virtual users is too low, just increase the number of threads in the Thread Group
   - JMeter cannot send requests fast enough because it's overloaded. Make sure to follow JMeter Best Practice and if it's still the case consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
   - Your application cannot respond fast enough. In your case I can see response times as high as 69589 milliseconds so most probably that is the reason, you need to ensure that the application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. using an [APM](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/top-10-application-performance-monitoring-tools/) tool, check its logs, check its configuration, perform code [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools), etc.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was under the impression the reason is the last one but I run again and saw that even if the max response time is significantly less then a second I still don't reach the expected rate. Furthermore, when I decrease the number of threads I still get to the same rate. So I guess I'm missing something.